# How to add widget to QSplashScreen after initial show()?

Tags: c++, qt, splash-screen, qsplashscreen

So my intended program flow is this:

1. Create, `show()` `QSplashScreen` instance.
2. Initialize other parts of system, including i18n module
3. Add (translated) copyright notice (`QLabel`) to `QSplashScreen` instance.

The problem is that unless I `hide()` the splash screen, call `QApplication::processEvents`, add the `QLabel`, and then re-`show()` the splash screen--causing a huge flicker obviously--the `QLabel` doesn't render.

That is, I do *not* see the notice if I merely write this:

```
QLabel* pSplashNotice = new QLabel( mpSplashScreen );
pSplashNotice->setObjectName( "SplashNotice" );
pSplashNotice->setWordWrap( true );
pSplashNotice->setText( Localize(my_text) );
pSplashNotice->resize( 1200, 50 );
pSplashNotice->move( 100, 1000 );

mpSplashScreen->raise();
mpSplashScreen->show();
```

I have to precede the above by

```
mpSplashScreen->hide();
QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
```

How can I get `pSplashNotice` to render without having to hide the splash screen?

Comment: Add you label and then call `mpSplashScreen->repaint();`

Comment: @Evgeny I tried this, that doesn't work.

Comment: Then try call `pSplashNotice->show()`

Comment: @Evgeny that did work.  Make your comment an answer and cash in on that sweet rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add following call

```
pSplashNotice->show();
```